# To Keg or not to Keg

Tags: fermentation, kegging

I've got a very lovely and quite potent American IPA that I've brewed several times now, from experience I know it'll get down to 1.006 in about 2 weeks if the temp is ideal.

The brew has been in for 2 weeks but as the ambient temperature has dropped so much it's only at 1.010 so not yet complete.

now my question! I either keg today or leave it for 2 weeks while I'm away, will it be ok on the yeast for another 2 weeks or should I just keg knowing that it's not yet complete? (my pressure keg should keep it at 15 psi)

Further question, if I do keg should I add the priming sugar or trust that the pressure that's inevitably going to be there from continued fermentation will be enough to carbonate?

I'm such a noob at this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really doesn't matter which you choose. 2 weeks is not so long that there will be a problem with leaving it. At the same time the gravity is reasonably close, it will be fine if you keg it.

One thing that might help make the decision, did you dry-hop or use hops after the boil? If you did the flavors extracted there are more volatile. I would lean towards kegging if that's the case.

When you do keg it, you do not need to use priming sugar. Force carbonating is great, and so much easier.

Answer (score 3):

2 weeks is no problem at all.  Leave it.

Answer (score 3):

1.010 is a good finishing gravity for most IPAs.

There's no need to add priming sugar if you're kegging. Force carbonate.